# Limit of Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the function $f=x^2$ defined over $[-\pi, \pi]$. It is clearly $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ so for any $m \geq 0$ I expect 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^m a_n = 0$$ 
where $a_n$ is the $n$th Fourier coefficient of $f$. The $a_n$ are given by something like 
$$\frac{4}{n^2} (-1)^n $$
Clearly then, choosing $m=2$ I get
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^2 a_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 4(-1)^n \neq 0$$ 
What's going on? If the decay of fourier coefficients does not apply to this function, to what functions does it apply?

Comment: Why do you expect the limit to be zero?

Comment: As a periodic function it is not smooth, it is Lipschitz. (@ThomasAndrews: If $f$ is $C^k$ then the the Fourier coefficients are $(in)^k \hat{f}(n)$ and Riemann Lebesgue gives the desired decay.)

Comment: Ok but then about what class of functions could we say that if they are m times regular that limit vanishes?

Comment: A theorem on a book I read says 2pi periodic, continuous, differentiable m times and with m-1 continuous derivatives implies that limit is zero

Comment: Yes, but the function you have is not differentiable at $x=\pm \pi$. That is enough to affect the Fourier series.

Comment: Why? If extended by periodicity over R, where do you see a discontinuity?

Comment: Yep, your function is not differentiable everywhere as a periodic function, specifically at $\pm \pi.$ It is continuous, but not differentiable.

Comment: Hmmm can you give me an example of one to which this theorem would apply?

Comment: Umm, $\sin, \cos$.

Comment: Look for the derivative property [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition)

Comment: Ok, the nondifferentiability seems very clear now, but what about non trivial examples that work? $\cos$ and $\sin$ make for a very short Fourier series